# How to filter change list by date?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I looked a bunch for a solution online. I need to get all submitted change lists between two dates. 
The find file does a good job at finding files changed between dates, but not change lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By command line, any changes integrated on any file on Depot path (and sub directories), at the end of September 2015.

```
  p4 changes -i -t //Depot/path/...@2015/09/21,2015/09/30
```

If you only want the submitted you must use

```
 p4 changes -s submitted -t //Depot/path/...@2015/09/21,2015/09/30
```

-t is there to display the date and makes sure you are correct.

If you want to see more options, you can go the [p4 changes manual page](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_changes.html).

Comment: Great! Thanks. The P4V GUI does not have this feature I assume.

Comment: @user3260977 No, currently it does not. However, Perforce does have an existing enhancement request to add the ability to find files by date submitted via a filter. I can add you to this request, if you would like.

Comment: You actually can in P4V, it's just a bit...unsupported. If you're on the submitted changelist pane, add a filter with the plus, and it'll be "Files". You can add a file path there with the syntax, e.g.  //depot/path/...@2015/01/01,@2015/01/31 and it will return any submitted changelists that fall under //depot/path/... between Jan 1st and Jan 31st of last year.